# How to derive a boolean from `location` in a Function Component

Tags: reactjs

I am practicing my React skills and need some assistance. I have a simple two-page website in which I need to render two reusable button components based on the path location. I have the console logs working showing the correct paths when you navigate the pages, but the boolean values are not changing based on the path: for example, if you are on the home ("/") page then you should see the Owner Login in button and if you are on the gallery ("/gallery") page you should see Search Images button.

My question what am I doing wrong, how do I get the buttons to render conditional based on the path location?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import Button from "./Button";

import styles from "./Header.module.css";

const Header = () => {
  const [isOnHomepage, setIsOnHomePage] = useState(false);

  const location = useLocation();
  console.log("currentpath:", location.pathname);

  const homeHandler = () => {
    if (location === "/") {
      setIsOnHomePage(true);
    }
  };
  console.log("status1", isOnHomepage);

  const galleryHandler = () => {
    if (location === "/gallery") {
      setIsOnHomePage(false);
    }
  };

  const buttonAction = () => {
    alert("Hello you clicked me!");
  };
  console.log("status2", isOnHomepage);

  return (
    <header className={styles["header-home"]}>
      <div className={styles["header-logo"]}>GalleryFunnizes!</div>
      {isOnHomepage && (
        <Button onClick={buttonAction} onHomeHandler={homeHandler}>
          Owner Login
        </Button>
      )}
      {!isOnHomepage && (
        <Button onClick={buttonAction} onGalleryHandler={galleryHandler}>
          Search Images
        </Button>
      )}
    </header>
  );
};

export default Header;



import styles from "./Button.module.css";

const Button = (props) => {
  return (
    <button
      className={styles.button}
      type={props.type || "button"}
      onClick={props.onClick}
    >
      {props.children}
    </button>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

Comment: What is the `onHomeHandler` attribute you have defined? I don't know of anything that recognises this

Comment: any chance you can add Button's code? I don't see anything on your code that changes the location.

Comment: @Codebling it is a function that I am trying to associate the conditional statements with, i did try  it with out the handlers and still have the same issue

Comment: @Julie do you have your router set up?

Comment: What I mean is that `onHomeHandler` is not a recognised attribute/property, as far as I know. It will never do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use state for `isOnHomepage`. The reason for this is `location` is already the source of truth for that. `isOnHomepage` is just being derived. If you store it as a separate state, then you have to keep it in sync -- every time `location` is changed, you also have to update the state (remember, the state persists across renders). This is not desirable as it is more work to maintain.

Instead, just use a regular old variable (React is just Javascript, after all) and derive it from the location.

```
const Header = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  console.log("currentpath:", location.pathname);

  const isOnHomePage = location.pathname === "/";

  //or, something closer to what you had:
  //let isOnHomePage;
  //if (location.pathname === "/") {
  //  isOnHomePage = true;
  //} else {
  //  isOnHomePage = false;
  //};


  return (
    <header className={styles["header-home"]}>
      {isOnHomepage && (
        <Button onClick={buttonAction} >
          Owner Login
        </Button>
      )}
      {!isOnHomepage && (
        <Button onClick={buttonAction} >
          Search Images
        </Button>
      )}
    </header>
  );
};
```

Comment: thank you for your help. I am trying to implement but I am getting error isOnHomePage is not defined

Comment: What do you have now? There may have been a typo in an earlier revision of my code - the one that is there now should work.

Comment: (I can see it, I had a lowercase 'p' in the code that I commented out. Switch the `let` to use an uppercase 'P' for `isOnHomePage`)

Answer (score 2):

The above answer by Codebling is correct, but I just wanted to add why yours doesn't work. It's better style to do what Codebling suggested but your version doesn't work because you are pasing some props `onHomeHandler` and `onGalleryHandler` that don't exist. If you just called it `onClick` instead it would work!

Like this:

```
return (
    <header className={styles["header-home"]}>
      <div className={styles["header-logo"]}>GalleryFunnizes!</div>
      {isOnHomepage && (
        <Button onClick={buttonAction} onClick={homeHandler}>
          Owner Login
        </Button>
      )}
      {!isOnHomepage && (
        <Button onClick={buttonAction} onClick={galleryHandler}>
          Search Images
        </Button>
      )}
    </header>
  );
```

Like I said, the solution that Codebling published is recommended because the code is simpler and easier to understand, but this was why yours wasn't working.

Comment: Nice. I was confused about these functions.

Comment: Even with `onClick`, one would still have to click a component before the correct one would display. Like you said, makes more sense to remove the state and just use variables with no functions

Comment: Thank you all for your help, I tried this as well, and still did not work, plus the onClicks were duplicate functions. Thank you @Codebling, I am still learning

Answer (score 1):

You need the Router set up before even try to use location, so I'm adding the missing parts here for you to move forward with it.

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <main>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
        <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
        <Route path="/gallery" component={Gallery} />
      </main>
    </Router>
  );
}

const Header = () => (
  const location = useLocation();
  const isHomepage = location.pathname === "/";


  return (
    <header className={styles["header-home"]}>
      {isOnHomepage && (
        <Link to="/login" >
          Owner Login
        </Link>
      )}
      {!isOnHomepage && (
        <Link to="/gallery" >
          Search Images
        </Link>
      )}
    </header>
  );
);

const Home = () => (
  <Fragment>
    <h1>Home</h1>
  </Fragment>
);

const Login = () => (
  <Fragment>
    <h1>Login</h1>
  </Fragment>
);

const Gallery = () => (
  <Fragment>
    <h1>Gallery</h1>
  </Fragment>
);
```

Comment: My assumption was that router had been set up in a parent component. Maybe I am wrong

Comment: Yeah... I thought the same, but Julie didn't answer my question so I put the whole thing.

Comment: I have my router already that was not the issue, but many thanks for your help